# UnboundLocalError: TRY EXCEPT STATEMENTS

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am currently creating a menu with `try except` tools. I'm trying to create it so if a user enters nothing (presses ENTER) to output:

> You have not entered anything, please enter a number between 1 and 4

[image: This is the error message(click here)]

This is what I've done so far:

```
def Menu():
    print("""
    Hello, please enter a number 1 - 4
        1 - Compliment
        2 - Fact
        3 - Insult
        4 - Quit
        """)
    try:
        UserInput_INT = int(input("> "))

    except ValueError:
        UserInput_STR = (UserInput_INT)

        if len(UserInput_STR) == 0:
            print("You have entered nothing. Please enter a number between 1 and 4")

        print("You entered a character. Please enter a number between 1 and 4")
        Menu()

    if UserInput_INT not in range (1, 5):
        print("Invalid input please enter a whole number between 1 and 4")


    UserInput_STR = (str(UserInput_INT))

    if UserInput_STR == '1':
        print(" You look horrible today!")

    elif UserInput_STR == '2':
        print("Sam Birkenshaw & Jordan Ives can code better than Mr Bath. ")

    elif UserInput_STR == '3':
        print("You are bad at coding ")

    elif UserInput_STR == '4':
        quit()

Menu()
```

Comment: What did are you trying to do in `UserInput_STR = (UserInput_INT)`?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/cf5AFY6.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the statement  `UserInput_STR = (UserInput_INT)` [*] you are accessing a variable that you did not initalize, since `int(input("> "))` have failed. Here's a shorter example:

```
def f():
    try:
        x = 2/0
    except:
        print(x)
```

What should `print(x)` do? the variable is indeed local, but is not bound. It is not initialized.

[*] I believe you meant something like `UserInput_STR = str(UserInput_INT)`, but it won't work either for the same reason.

Answer (score 1):

Try this and its same as you expected your output to be.

```
 UserInput=input("> ")
 try:
    UserInput_INT = int(UserInput)
```

So here we first input into UserInput_INT and then in the try block we cast it to integer type.

Comment: You've added one line and copied their entire program over. Instead, provide that line, maybe a few surrounding lines for context, and **why this fixes the issue**. See [answer]

Comment: it still says that i need to define UserInput_INT outside the try statement.

Comment: @Sam.Birkenshaw - not necessarily. Just don't use it in the `except` clause. And you don't need it there, since it's meaningless.

Comment: But i need to convert it into a string to be able to find the length of it

Comment: The input starts as a string, so you can find its length.