# I get an UnboundLocalError when I pass in a string

Tags: python

I am new to python and I wanted to practice about `try/except` but I got stuck:

```
def monitor():
    try:
        brightness = int(input("brightness:"))
    except ValueError:
        print("please pass in a number")

    if brightness < -1 or brightness > 101:
        print("invaild",brightness)
    else:
        print("invalid",brightness)

while True:
    monitor()
```

I expect there will be no error when I type a string but it gives me:

```
UnboundLocalError
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnboundLocalError: TRY EXCEPT STATEMENTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553672/unboundlocalerror-try-except-statements)

Comment: when you type string then you get `ValueError` in `int()` and it doesn't create variable `brightness`. You may assign value to `brightness` in `except` to create variable or assign some value before `try` to create this variable at start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code fragment

```
try:
    brightness = int(input("brightness:"))
except ValueError:
    print("please pass in a number")

print(brightness)
```

What should be output of `print(brightness)` if one enters *"A bit dark"* when asked for input?

Because input is not an integer, `int()` will throw exception in this case, so local variable `brightness` will not be initialized.

You could either have it initialized to some default value in `except` clause, but in this case you probably shouldn't do anything with brighntess value if input was incorrect.

You can move logic processing `brightness` inside try...except, then it will execute only if input can be parsed.

```
def monitor():
    try:
        brightness = int(input("brightness:"))

        if brightness < -1 or brightness > 101:
            print("invaild",brightness)
        else:
            print("invalid",brightness)

    except ValueError:
        print("please pass in a number")
```

Comment: @niimet no problem, you can always accept an answer if you feel it helped

Answer (score 0):

Please check this, here we are forcing user to type only integer value.

```
    brightness=-2
while (brightness < -1 or brightness > 101):
    try:
        brightness = int(input("brightness:"))
    except ValueError:
        print("please pass in a number")


if brightness < -1 or brightness > 101:
   print("invaild",brightness)
else:
   print("Valid",brightness)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead (this fixes your asked problem):

```
def monitor():
    while True:
        try:
            brightness = int(input("brightness:"))
            if brightness < -1 or brightness > 101:
                print("invaild",brightness)
            if brightness < -1 or brightness > 101:
                print("invaild",brightness)

            else:
                print("invalid",brightness)
        except ValueError:
            print("please pass in a number")


        else:
            print("invalid",brightness)


monitor()
```

Your code has a **Logical error** too as whatever input (brighteness), output will always be `print("invalid",brightness)`

**Telling you if you are not aware, in case.**

Your codes output:

[image: Your Code output]

My output:

[image]

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, you can always choose this as best answer.

Comment: Why write `1==1`? Why not just type `True`?

Comment: this code has the same problem as original code - it doesn't create variable `brightness` when there is `ValueError` and then in line `if brightness` it gives the sam error `UnboundLocalError`.

Comment: @dangee1705 that does not matter.

Comment: @furas no you are wrong I edited my answer and gave proof, you can see it.

Comment: no, you are wrong. First answer `"hey"` and you get error `"UnboundLocalError"`. When you first asnwer "2" then it creates variable and next answer `"hey"` don't get error but any text as first answer gives error.

Comment: @Hisham___Pak it does matter because not only is writing `1==1` just bad form it's actually slower than writing `True`

Comment: @dangee1705 bro you are arguing on just a little thing.

Comment: I'm not arguing I'm telling you it's bad practice, less efficient, and since you are teaching someone else, you should use the correct method.

Comment: @dangee1705 yeah that I know, when I was testing the code in compiler it was not accepting True so I did this and I was lazy to replace it, and just pasted here without replacing. So now I am going to edit it. okay?